# Django migration issues when changing model field

Tags: django

we have a Model with a field such as

```
from core import snippets

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey, ParentalManyToManyField


tags = ParentalManyToManyField(
        snippets.Tag,
        blank=True,
    )
```

we have changed the snippets import from

```
from readiness import snippets
to
from core import snippets
```

where snippets is just the same but moved to the core app

getting migration errors

```
tags was declared with a lazy reference to 'readiness.tag', but app 'readiness' isn't installed.
```